# Вычислить сумму и число положительных элементов матрицы A[N, N]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задание: Вычислить сумму и число положительных элементов матрицы A[N, N], находящихся над главной диагональю.

Я сделал код, правда только не совсем работает так: Вывод положительных чисел не может убрать отрицательные (т.е. например: 2 3 4 5 -1, а вывод получается: 5, хотя должно быть 4). Также правильно ли я сделал с суммой, если я сделал с рандомным значением (Выводит при вводе 2 1 2 3 4: 48, потом 52, 37 и т.д.)? Заранее благодарю.

```py
import random
pol = 0
s=0
i=0
k=1
aar = []
N=int(input('Ввод: '))
A=[[random.randrange(10) for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
for row in range(N):
    for col in range(row + 1, N):
         s+=A[row][col]

for row in range(N):
    aar.append(input())
    if N > 0:
        pol += 1
print('Сумма:', s)
print('Число:', pol)
```

Comment: pol у вас всегда равно N, независимо от того, что вы вводите. В качестве упражнения можете найти причину этого. А зачем вам второй цикл вообще непонятно. Нужно же считать числа в матрице, а не те, которые вводятся вручную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это же можно сделать более эффективно:

```
import random
pol = 0
s = 0
N = int(input('Ввод: '))
A = [[random.randrange(10) for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        if A[i][j] <= 0:
           continue
        if A[i][j] > 0:
            pol += 1
            s += A[i][j]

print('Сумма:', s)
print('Число:', pol)
```

Или даже при генерации данных (при считывании, без хранения матрицы):

```
import random


pol = 0
s = 0
N = int(input('Ввод: '))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        a_ij = random.randrange(10)
        if a_ij <= 0:
           continue
        if a_ij > 0:
            pol += 1
            s += a_ij

print('Сумма:', s)
print('Число:', pol)
```

Comment: Так а разве должно быть, что сумма и числа генерируются рандомно? Даже проверил такой случай: 19 и 19 вывел.

Comment: @LaurasiaUltima Ну так Вы попросили найти сумму элементов матрицы. Возможно, она случайно сгенерирована

Comment: Понял, надо больше мне изучать Python ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А где учитывается `находящихся над главной диагональю.`? Кстати, интерпретация - чего именно сумму считать - сомнительная (и у автора тоже).

Comment: @MBo плохо прочитал. Ща поправлю.

Comment: @MBo спасибо. Готово

Comment: @hedgehogues Ну что-то не то опять. `for j in range(i+1, N):` в первом варианте достаточно, во втором  `if j <= i:`

Comment: @MBo минусаните мой вопрос (=. Ну, я правда, не очень ответил )=

Comment: @MBo зачем во втором if менять? Можно же цикл ограничить и проверять на <= 0 элементы.

Comment: Смотрите - в обоих случаях отсечение отрицательных `if A[i][j] <= 0:` лишнее. Во втором случае `for j` ведь нельзя менять - матрицу заполнить надо всю, наверное, а вот проверка индекса к месту `if (j > i) and (aij >0):

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107673/discussion-between-hedgehogues-and-mbo).